Queue Gets "poisoned" when trying to execute a stored proc with an OpenQuery call in it
I have a service broker queue with an activation procedure to read and process the messages. The activation proc reads in the XML message (@cmd) and executes the contents using a simple statement
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd

The commands being sent in messages to the queue are simply the names of other stored procedures in the database that I'd like to run asynchronously. However, if the stored proc contains an OpenQuery command against a linked Oracle server in the SQL Server instance, the messages get poisoned and the queue gets disabled.
Importantly (or, maybe importantly?) this only happens if the activation procedure is enabled to automatically processes the messages in the queue (STATUS=ON). If the stored proc in the message does not contain an OpenQuery, it behaves normally and the message is processed and everything is fine.
If I set the activation status to OFF, the OpenQuery message gets written to the queue and sits there. When I run the manually Activation Procedure myself, everything works fine. Which leads me to think it's a permissions issue. I have the queue set to execute as Self, but something is going wrong.
Here is the definition for the queue:
CREATE QUEUE  CallQueue
  WITH        STATUS = ON
            , ACTIVATION  ( STATUS            = ON
                          , PROCEDURE_NAME    = MyDb.schema.sbCallHandler 
                          , MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 10
                          , EXECUTE AS          SELF)

I've tried putting a try/catch blocks in the call handler and monitoring error codes, but all to no avail.
Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on, or how I might shed light on the root issue?
Again, if I simply execute MyDb.schema.sbCallHandler by hand (rather than letting it be run by the queue) everything works fine, but I'd like it to automatically process messages that arrive in the queue.
I haven't been able to catch or reveal the underlying error, which is probably a result of not knowing where to look.
Thank you.
Here is the body of the stored proc:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [schema].[sbCallHandler] AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @ch               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
  DECLARE @messagetypename  NVARCHAR(256)
  DECLARE @messagebody      XML
  DECLARE @responsemessage  XML
  DECLARE @Cmd              NVARCHAR(MAX)

  BEGIN TRANSACTION ;
    RECEIVE TOP(1)  @ch               = conversation_handle
                  , @messagetypename  = message_type_name
                  , @messagebody      = CAST(message_body AS XML)
    FROM            MyDb.schema.CallQueue

    IF (@messagetypename IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
        IF ( @messagetypename = 'CallType' ) 
          BEGIN
            Set @Cmd = @messagebody.value('/ExecCommand[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            EXEC sp_executesql @Cmd
            SET @responsemessage = '<svcResponse>'
                  + @messagebody.value('/ExecCommand[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                  + '</svcResponse>' ;
            SEND ON CONVERSATION @ch MESSAGE TYPE ResponseType (@responsemessage) ;
            END CONVERSATION @ch ;
          END
      END
  COMMIT TRANSACTION

END


@DaleK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/handling-poison-messages?view=sql-server-ver16

Sounds like there is some kind of rollback happening. Have you checked the logs to see if there are any errors there? What about setting up an XE event session to monitor for errors https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/capture-sql-server-reported-errors-using-extended-events Can you show the code for the actual procedure as well?

Do you see anything interesting in SELECT * FROM sys.transmission_queue?

also, what's the setting for the linked server login? I'm guessing the error you're getting is: Linked servers cannot be used under impersonation without a mapping for the impersonated login. You can try doing the OPENQUERY in dynamic sql, which might help try/catching the error

Thank you for these suggestions - the body of the stored proc is added above.
siggemannen, I'll try the suggestion of the openqry in dynamic sql today. And when you say the setting for the linked server login, can you help me understand a bit more what the answer looks like? It's going against an odbc datasource on the machine...
And no, when I've checked sys.transmission_queue it's been empty.
Thank you!

This is a long-shot (based on my experience with Service Broker) but Service Broker can have permission problems cross-database due to obscure issues with which login is used. You can test these by setting TRUSTWORTHY ON on the database with the Service Broker, to see if that allows the broker to do it. You should set trustworthy off again, but if that allowed your process to work, you'll need to consider the alternatives (which involves signing procedures etc).
